# how to play videos in .avi file format in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, embedded-resource

Technically It was possible to play .avi files by loading an embedded object for a external player directly in the HTML. Now   [chrome deprecated](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en) that capabitilities and the solution left it's to transcode all my video files into .mp4

**Edited**
Because I don't own the files I don't pretend to transcode them. I'm looking forward for a way to re-enable the old embedded objects to play those files into the browser. **Chrome is required**

**For firefox a solution would be:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <object id="MediaPlayer1" width="690" height="500" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"
  codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
    standby="Loading Microsoft® Windows® Media Player components..." type="application/x-oleobject">
    <param name="FileName" value='My File Name' />
    <param name="AutoStart" value="True" />
    <param name="DefaultFrame" value="mainFrame" />
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="0" />
    <param name="ShowPositionControls" value="0" />
    <param name="showcontrols" value="0" />
    <param name="ShowAudioControls" value="0" />
    <param name="ShowTracker" value="0" />
    <param name="EnablePositionControls" value="0" />
    <embed  type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/"
           src='MY_AVI_FILE.avi' align="middle" width="600" height="500" defaultframe="rightFrame"
           id="MediaPlayer2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are only a few file video formats which can be played in most browsers.  Chrome probably does not want to support non-standard formats and thus pollute the Web with incompatible content.

Here are the video formats supported by various browsers:

```
+--------------------+----------------------+-------+-----+
|      Browser       |         MP4          | WebM  | Ogg |
+--------------------+----------------------+-------+-----+
| Internet Explorer  | YES                  | NO    | NO  |
| Chrome             | YES                  | YES   | YES |
| Firefox            | YES                  | YES   | YES |
| Safari             | YES                  | NO    | NO  |
| Opera              | YES (from Opera 25)  | YES   | YES |
+--------------------+----------------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Chrome is restricted but I'm looking forward for an hack where I can re-enable the capabitilities of embedded objects into the chrome browser. The @Suneel refers an application that does ensure compatibility between any source of media with the browsers specification by transcoding the file but as i mentioned in the comment above i don't pretend to transcode the files because I don't own them.

Answer (score 1):

I invented an alternative for Npapi windows media player!

My windows program is an extension for all browsers installed on the computer. And it can be very interesting complement any browser functionality.
For example I have added to my site (example site, with part of code: http://master255.org/) mpc-hc player with feedback to view any video from the site.

It sounds fantastic? But it works! :-D

Program Code:

https://github.com/master255/Redirector

Download:

http://master255.org/setup/setup.exe

Enjoy!