# Play .avi files from google drive in html5

Tags: html, video, google-drive-api

Is there any way to play .avi files from google drive in html5 (in google chrome)?
I have been searching for hours and I was not able to find anything, there is some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628054/how-to-play-videos-in-avi-file-format-in-chrome) that could work in firefox but I was wondering if there was any alternative for google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Chrome does not support avi. You must convert them to mp4.